# My first store redirecting to the second one in magento multisite

Tags: php, magento

I am new to Magento and trying to make multiple website.

I made some wrong settings in the secure and insecure URL, and due to that a problem has occurred.

If I type my new store name in URL it will redirect to the secondary domain. I can't even open the admin panel to change the URL.

Does any one know which table has this secure and insecure URL settings? What do I have to change in it?

Answer (score 1):

The settings you're after are found in the **`core_config_data`** table.

```
web/unsecure/base_url
web/secure/base_url
```

But if in doubt you can always search your database for the fields you're after.